# Checking if throwError happened

Tags: haskell, monads

`(StateT Env (ErrorT String IO)) ()` is my stack of monads. I use `throwError` function to abort computation and propagate information about error. I am aware of the fact that it is sense of `ErrorT` monad - abort and propagate error.

However, the question is: is it possible to check if error was thrown?

I mean:

```
res <- computeSomething -- it may throw error
case (error was thrown) of
      True -> do something
      False -> do something else
```

Comment: That’s pretty much what `catchError` is for.

Comment: Thanks you very much!